# Do I need to separate /var and /tmp from the root partition on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

A result of an audit check on the Amazon Linux AMI gave a number of recommendations on the file structure, for example the need to have the root and /var and /tmp on different partitions.

Is this still advisable practices in the public cloud world or hang over from on-prem hardware and VM infrastructure?

Comment: /var has logfiles and /tmp has temporary files, both of which can potentially fill up quickly. Separate /var and /tmp partitions are best practice because if they get filled up, it won't stop your operational systems from functioning as they should be using other directories.Of course if you send all your logfiles to another server and limit what gets written to /tmp, separate partitions are not offering much value.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are doing.

Traditionally, /var and /tmp are separate because that is what gets written to regularly, and if a runaway process generates lots of output, this fills up only one of the less important partitions, so while services may become unavailable (and should gracefully bow out and return temporary error codes), interactive logons still work so one can log in and investigate.

In addition, it means that when /var becomes more and more fragmented as files of different sizes are created and deleted, that doesn't spill over to the root partition.

If you are working with lots of small files, a different blocks-to-inodes ratio on /var might also make sense.

If either of these is a concern for you, the split still makes sense, otherwise not so much.

Comment: Guessing it depends on the lifespan of the EC2 instance as well, ephemeral instances created by an ASG probably not going to give much benefit, longer lived instances might have some benefit.

Comment: I'd pretty much always keep /tmp and /var/tmp on tmpfs anyway -- these aren't meant to survive reboots, so there is no point wasting IOPS on them.

Comment: `/var/tmp` does survive reboots on Debian/Ubuntu, and I believe files there are auto-deleted less frequently on RedHat-derived distros.